# How bind button inside user control to another ViewModel

Tags: wpf, datacontext

I'm working on project that based on WPF and MVVM.
I have some UserControl (summaryView) which has DataContext to ViewModel(SummaryVM).
I want put a button in  summaryView and set the button DataContex to another viewModel(MainWindowViewModel) but it's not working for me.

This is the NameSpace of the ViewModel

```
xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:ContentSync.ViewModel"
```

This is my button

```
<Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="100" Height="30" Margin="0,20" DataContex=... Command="{Binding ModifyUserSettingsCommand}">Modify</Button>
```

The command `ModifyUserSettingsCommand` is located at MainWindowViewModel and the but I don't know how to bind it to my button. I think I need to set it`s DataContext but I didn't succeed in figuring out what is the right syntax

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to UserControl reousrces this:

```
 <UserControl.Resources>
        <vm:MainWindowViewModel x:Key="btnViewModel" />
 </UserControl.Resources>
```

And with that way you must assign DataContext to Button:

```
DataContext="{StaticResource btnViewModel}"
```